# Linux shared library: replace symbol runtime

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I have a quite large C application consisting of several shared libraries. One of the core libraries has a function

```
void common_function(const char * arg) { ... }
```

Which is called by all the other libraries. During testing I would like to use a different test implementation of the `common_function`.

My plan has been to create a test library containing the alternate implementation of `common_function`; is it at all possible to replace the default `common_function` runtime using `dlopen() / dlsym()` trickery, or alternatively would this link line:

```
gcc -o test.c -ltest -lcommon
```

ensure that the `common_function` implementation in libtest.so was used also in the libcommon.so - altough the latter has it's own implementation of `common_function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Drepper's paper: How To Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and wikipage on [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker#ELF-based_Unix-like_systems).

You probably want to play the [`LD_PRELOAD` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)  (assuming all your libraries are shared, not static).

Answer (score 0):

If you write an implementation of `common_function` in `test.c`, the linker will use that and therefore the loader won't even try to load it from a  library (static or dynamic).

What you want is a [*mock*](https://circleci.com/blog/how-to-test-software-part-i-mocking-stubbing-and-contract-testing/) (that page example uses Python to illustrate the concept but it holds for any language).

My personal favourite mocking framework for C is [FFF](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff) ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65238678/6271889) an example of how to use it). There's also [C-Mock](https://github.com/hjagodzinski/C-Mock).